# ADO.NET: Can't connect to mdf database file

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net, connection-string

I'm writing an application that uses a SQL Server 2005 database. In the connection string I'm specifying the mdf file like this:

```
connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=" + fileLocation + "; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True";
```

When I execute the code:

```
public static void forceConnection()
{
    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(conn != null)
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I receive an exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

This code works on XP but not in Vista. I tried to run Visual Studio in admin mode and moved the mdf file to "user data" folders but the error persists.

Any help?

Comment: In the sql server, if you connect to the database , is it getting connected or not..if you get tis error in exception, the same error you will get if you open your server too. this is the logic behind it

Comment: If i attach my mdf to database, i can connect. However that's not the behaviour i want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you connect to the sql server db in your command prompt? I would make sure you can actually connect first.

Try open the cmd prompt and type `sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d your_dbase`

Comment: You right, i can't.. :S I receive "Error locating Server/instance specified [xFFFFFFF]"

Comment: @Nabo, you can't because your database name is not what you trying.

Comment: Damn... The database name changed when i moved from pc and is not "SQLEXPRESS" anymore.. I consider this answer as right because it was the most usefull from all. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to diagnose your issue and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If I have mssql-connect problems with my dotnet-sourcecode I try to connect to the database with a different program. I use [queryexpress](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) that is also written in dotnet. If this program works then I know that the problem is with my program code else the problem is with connection string, proxy, network, sqlserver or user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have sqlexpress installed? does it use the machineName\sqlexpress or does it run as a default instance?

You have to verify these cases.

and you might wanna use the actual machineName\instance name if you aren't using the default instance.

Comment: Yes i have sql server installed. And if i try a direct connection to sql server (adding "Database=..." to connection string) it works. Having ".\SQLEXPRESS" or "{myMachineName}\SQLEXPRESS" produces the same result.